# Do I need to include "Windows.h" to use/communciate with the WindowsAPI implicitly?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, header

Citation from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) of "Windows.h" (emphasize mine):

> "windows.h is a Windows-specific header file for the C and C++ programming languages which contains declarations for all of the functions in the Windows API, all the common macros used by Windows programmers, and all the data types used by the various functions and subsystems. It defines a very large number of Windows specific functions** that can be used in C. **The Win32 API can be added to a C programming project by including the  header file and linking to the appropriate libraries**. To use functions in xxxx.dll, the program **must be linked to xxxx.lib (or libxxxx.dll.a in MinGW)**. Some headers are not associated with a .dll but with a static library (e.g. scrnsave.h needs scrnsave.lib). "

---

My question:

Do I need to include the header file of `windows.h` into my C/C++ project, if I want my executable file (which was created to run on Windows only) to communicate with/use the WindowsAPI implicitly?

Or does the compiler that automatically if I didn´t specified it else and want to access the WindowsAPI implicitly?

What I mean is not to explicitly use functions, macros or datatypes defined in `windows.h`. Rather, If I want to access components of the WindowsAPI implicitly through the shell, f.e. by using cmd.exe or PowerShell.

Comment: What happened when you tried not doing it?

Comment: @user253751 I created executables which run fine one Windows without it. I do not know if I need to include it for any specific reason.

Comment: And do you use the Windows API in your code?

Comment: Windows.h needs to be included for some things in the WindowsAPI, but not everything. If you can get away without including it, then great -- it defines a lot of junk.

Comment: @user253751 No, not yet. But I don´t know if parts of it do or need to have it included or have an alternative ifor anything in the standard libraries but rather use functions macros etc. from the "Windows.h" for better conformance.

Comment: Okay, what happened when you tried using the Windows API but you didn't include Windows.h?

Comment: @user253751 I do not use the WindowsAPI explicitly in the program, but do not know if parts of my program need to have access to it, since it shall run on Windows.

Comment: Also do you need to include <stdio.h> to use printf?

Comment: @user253751 Doesn´t the console of f.e. PowerShell interact with the WindowsAPI, too?

Comment: This is somewhat evil but you could use `<cstdlib>` and call `int system(const char* command);`. No `windows.h` needed.

Comment: @gavxn Cool. How do I create a thread with console commands?

Comment: In C and C++, a symbol must have been declared at the point where it is used. A header file is a common way to introduce symbols exposed by a library. If you are using a library, you have to make the symbols known to the compiler. You can either include its header file, or declare the symbol yourself. For example, if you're using the C++ thread support library, you `#include <thread>`. The implementation will use the Windows API, but you are not required to resolve the library's dependencies. I.e., if you are using `<thread>` you are not required to `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah not possible. For other stuff, maybe. [The win32 api is accessible through powershell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/). And it goes without saying that this is a workaround for proper usage of the win32 api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applies not only to "Windows.h" with Win32 API but to (almost) any header file related to a certain API. As a general rule, I would say that you don't need to include a header until you actually need it. And whether you need it or not in most cases is stated in API documentation.

For example, [documentation for CreateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) tells you that you need to `include Windows.h`

So until you will actually use this or another function (macro, class, #definition, etc.) you don't need to #include corresponding header.

Answer (score 3):

`windows.h` is a "super header" including pretty much everything imaginable. Specific parts of the Win API have their own headers too, so you can as well just include those you are interested in.

Look up the specific API function on MSDN. If it specifies that the function resides in a specific header, then you might get away with only including that header. If it compiles & links fine, then you didn't need windows.h.